# Google chrome local storage on mac

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, local-storage

I am working with local storage techniques on a website that I'm building, so far with great success because I cant see the popup again. Where is the folder that contains the local storage and within that folder what name should I be looking for? Something specific to the name I called it in javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome currently stores local storage data under the path:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/$PROFILE/Local Storage
```

where `$PROFILE` is either `Default` if you have not logged into a profile, or something along the lines of `Profile 1` if you have.

Note that there is one file per site, not per stored value, and the files are SQLite databases. You will not be able to read their contents in a text editor.

If all you want to do is *view* the contents of local storage, you may want to consider instead using an extension along the lines of [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb?hl=en).